# Twilio Queue Connecting to the wrong call

Tags: twilio

I am working with a twilio queue and I have multiple numbers that come into the queue. The operator receives a popup and it shows the department that a customer is calling into (based on the twilio number they dial).

Like:

- Technical support   [has it's own number]
- Customer Service [has it's own number]
- Sales [has it's own number]

I am presenting this info to the operator and when they accept the call it connects the operator to the queue and pops off the top.

**The issue:** If another call comes in it pops someone off the top of the queue and they may have called a different department. So, the info I am showing to the operator is not accurate. The first person in the queue may have called sales, and someone else calls technical support. The operator answers technical support when they really called sales. So I am displaying bad info.

I know they have twilio task router. But, is it possible to solve this with the queue? Essentially I want to be able to identify what number someone called which categorizes it into the right department.

Can I pop a specific call off the queue based on call SID or something like that so I know I am delivering the right call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have a couple of options here.

You could enqueue the calls coming in to your support/customer service/sales numbers into differently named queues. That way, when an operator accepts a sales call, they will only dial into the sales queue.

Alternatively, instead of dialling the queue, you could [use the REST API to update the queued call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource), redirecting it to connect to your operator another way. For example, if your operator accepts the call they could [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) into a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) and at the same time redirect the call, via the REST API, to that conference too.